# LinkedIn API Network Updates

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm having problems extractin LinkedIn Network Updates using API methods.

I can extract my SHAR and CMPY Network Updates but when I try to filter CONN, VIRL or other types I get different types of Network Updates. Let me explain to you.

This
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/network/updates:(update-type)?type=SHAR&count=100

works and returns:

```
<updates total="120" count="70" start="0">
    <update>
        <update-type>SHAR</update-type>
    </update>
    <update>
        <update-type>SHAR</update-type>
    </update>
    ...
</updates>
```

This
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/network/updates:(update-type)?type=VIRL&count=100

does not work, returning:

```
<updates total="201" count="94" start="0">
    <update>
       <update-type>CONN</update-type>
    </update>
    <update>
        <update-type>SHAR</update-type>
    </update>
    <update>
        <update-type>VIRL</update-type>
    </update>
    ...
</updates>
```

Has LinkedIn changed the Network Updates types?

Answer (score 0):

VIRL updates are those on which the person had acted upon (liked or commented). So it can include various other updates. The original update is under original-update.

**I have used JSON output so it looks like this:**
[image: The VIRL update contents]

**And on expanding the originalUpdate key; it looks like this:**

[image: The VIRL originalUpdate contents]